# Hottest news + big image + link + intro text in Joomla

Tags: joomla, joomla-extensions, joomla3.0

I would like to show one of a featured article + image + link + few line from article like on this site:

http://www.origo.hu/index.html

As you can see on the link, on the top part of the side the visitor see a big image (with the most important news for example) with the link/name of the article and under this a few line from the article.

Any idea how to do this in Joomla 3?

Comment: This question features a link to a live site, and as such it is as risk of the remote site not illustrating the effect desired (which may have happened already, or will do so in the future). We want questions to be entirely (or at least mostly) self-contained here. An edit to bring an image into the question would be very welcome (even if it remains rather broad).

Answer (score 0):

You probably should have done some more research on this.

You could simply customize the featured layout like Elin suggests.

However I would suggest using K2, this is a powerfull content creation tool (replaces the articlemanagement in Joomla). This extensions gives you more control over your content. It does require a little bit of knowledge on html and css.

http://getk2.org/

Comment: I'm sorry but he's asking for nothing but a featured layout, why would you recommend that he do that?

Comment: Arguably you are right that if his question is only to change the featured layout, he could (with some effort) change this (I will update my answer). I did read from his question that he would like more control over how his content looks in general, in that case k2 is for me a far more elegant and less labor intensive solution.

Answer (score 0):

The standard featured layout will do what you say, you just will want to make a layout override to display the intro image, into text and any ther links in a custom way.  You could also do the same thing with tags (make a tag "hot news" for example).